# Error: Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string .NET SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I realise this question has been asked before, but after going through the previously answered questions, i still can't quite figure out what's wrong with this code.

FYI I am in the UK.

```
   public static void GetDataForCSEP(string viewName, string schemaName, 
                                             string dateFieldName, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {

            string dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";


            //Connect to SQl Server 

            string commandText = "SELECT * FROM " + schemaName + "." + viewName + " WHERE @dateFieldName BETWEEN @startDate AND  @endDate";


            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(commandText,sql_Conn))
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@dateFieldName",SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = dateFieldName;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(startDate.ToString(dateFormat));
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(startDate.ToString(dateFormat));



                sql_Conn.Open();
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you doing `DateTime.Parse(startDate.ToString(dateFormat))` - `startDate` is already a DateTime value. Why convert it to string just to convert it back?

Comment: Because i'm a rubbish programmer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Error is you cannot pass column name as parameter

```
    "SELECT * FROM " + schemaName + "." + viewName + " 
WHERE @dateFieldName BETWEEN @startDate AND  @endDate";
```

this should be

```
    "SELECT * FROM " + schemaName + "." + viewName + " 
WHERE " + dateFieldName  + " BETWEEN @startDate AND  @endDate";
```

To avoid sqlInjection attack make use of `Sp_executeSQL` to execute this type of query, because this is dynamic sql query.

Comment: Agreed, as structured the code will attempt to check whether the Static String `@dateFieldName` is between two dates.  To do this the SQL Engine is attempting to convert the text value of `@dateFieldName` into a date, and failing.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on your SQL Server locale settings, but perhaps

```
string dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

will work for you?

Comment: THanks, how do i find out those settings? It's login specific isn't it?

Comment: Yes and no - there'll be defaults, but you can also modify them for the duration of a user's connection etc. I'd check Books Online, as I'm not so familiar with the DBA side!